# atlassian's Bitbucket service unable to start (CentOS 7)

Tags: centos, centos7

On my CentOS 7 Server i installed Bitbucket, for some reason it crashed two days ago, i am trying to get it back running on my server but faced some difficulties enabling the service with the cmldlets :

```
   systemctl enable bitbucket.service
   systemctl start bitbucket.service
```

The latter returning the message :

> Control Process exited, code=exited status=203/EXEC

when i enter my bitbucket credentials from the `bitbucket.properties` file.

What could be the problem and what could be the solution to this case ?

Thank you for the great help.

Comment: Run `systemctl status bitbucket.service`.

Comment: i thought it retuned the same error 203, but `service atlbitbucket start` returned the error message : "JRE_HOME not set correctly, set set-jre-home.sh and JRE_HOME var "